# Dependency injection with FastAPI problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, dependency-injection, fastapi, pydantic

I am getting an error when using dependency_overrides
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-dependencies/

I have sample project (in attachment) with the following structure:

**service.py**

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
class Service(BaseModel):
    key: int
    name: str
```

**handler.py**

```
from service import Service

class ServiceHandler:
    async def get_all(self):
        return [Service(**x) for x in
                [{'key': 1, 'name': 'One'},
                 {'key': 2, 'name': 'Two'}]]
```

**factory.py**

```
from fastapi import Depends
from handler import ServiceHandler

async def get_service_handler(handler=Depends(ServiceHandler)):
    return handler
```

**main.py**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter, Depends
import factory

router = APIRouter()
@router.get("/services/", tags=["services"])
async def get_services(handler=Depends(factory.get_service_handler)):
    return await handler.get_all()

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(router)

and pytest+pytest-mock unit test for route:
```

**unit_tests/test.py**

```
import...
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def client():
    return TestClient(app)

def test_get_services(client, mocker):
    handler = ServiceHandler()
    mocker.patch.object(handler, 'get_all')
    handler.get_all.return_value = [Service(_id=None, key=1, name='Test')]
    app.dependency_overrides[factory.get_service_handler] = handler

    response = client.get("/services")

    assert response.status_code == 200
    # expected = [{'_id': None, 'key': 1, 'name': 'Test'}]
    expected = [{'_id': None, 'key': 1, 'name': 'One'}, {'_id': None, 'key': 2, 'name': 'Two'}]
    assert response.json() == expected

    app.dependency_overrides = {}
```

When I ran it with:
`pytest unit_tests/test.py`
I got an **exception**:
`FAILED unit_tests/test.py::test_get_services - TypeError: <handler.ServiceHandler object at 0x7fd03d813b50> is not a callable object`

I tried to add **call** to handler.py as follows

```
...
class ServiceHandler:
    def __call__(self):
        pass
...
```

and **another exception** happened:
`FAILED unit_tests/test.py::test_get_services - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_all'`

After all, if I start the server:
`hypercorn main:app --reload`
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/services/`
everything works well in any way.

If I comment out the line in test.py:

```
...
app.dependency_overrides[factory.get_service_handler] = handler
...
```

then the test will work, so I guess the cause of the problem is in dependency_overrides.

[depends_demo.zip](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/files/5364406/depends_demo.zip)

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the content of your `unit_tests/test.py`:

```
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from handler import ServiceHandler
import factory
from service import Service
import pytest
from main import app
import asyncio
from unittest.mock import AsyncMock
    


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def client():
    return TestClient(app)

def test_get_services(client, mocker):
    handler = ServiceHandler()

    async_mock = AsyncMock(return_value=[Service(_id=None, key=1, name='Test')])
    mocker.patch('handler.ServiceHandler.get_all', side_effect=async_mock)
    app.dependency_overrides[factory.get_service_handler()] = handler

    response = client.get("/services")

    assert response.status_code == 200
    # expected = [{'_id': None, 'key': 1, 'name': 'Test'}]
    expected = [{'_id': None, 'key': 1, 'name': 'One'}, {'_id': None, 'key': 2, 'name': 'Two'}]
    assert response.json() == expected

    app.dependency_overrides = {}
```

Two things that solved the problem:

- You need to call the get_service_handler to get the handler:

`app.dependency_overrides[factory.get_service_handler()] = handler`

- Maybe you need async mocks for async functions, so i read about it here: https://dino.codes/posts/mocking-asynchronous-functions-python/. There it says that if you are above python3.8, AsyncMock should be used:

```
async_mock = AsyncMock(return_value=[Service(_id=None, key=1, name='Test')])
mocker.patch('handler.ServiceHandler.get_all', side_effect=async_mock)
```

Now I run the tests with `pytest unit_tests/test.py  -v` this is what I get:

```
E       AssertionError: assert [{'key': 1, 'name': 'Test'}] == [{'_id': None...name': 'Two'}]
E         At index 0 diff: {'key': 1, 'name': 'Test'} != {'_id': None, 'key': 1, 'name': 'One'}
E         Right contains one more item: {'_id': None, 'key': 2, 'name': 'Two'}
E         Full diff:
E         - [{'_id': None, 'key': 1, 'name': 'One'}, {'_id': None, 'key': 2, 'name': 'Two'}]
E         + [{'key': 1, 'name': 'Test'}]
```